# Where to ask questions about the C# language?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have some questions about C# language (e.g. the solution to bugs, how to finish a C# program)

1. Which site should I post them on?
2. What tags should I choose?

Comment: First please describe what kind of questions: programming with C? Questions about the history of C language? Something else?

Comment: Stackoverflow is your best option!

Comment: @ManojKumar Not if the question is about the history of c#. OP should be specific.

Comment: @Patrick But he has mentioned solution of bugs.

Comment: How can i answer below nice comments? >< I am a beginner

Comment: @ManojKumar did you see a "#" that I missed? Anyway, Stack Overflow is only for **programming** - there are other questions about C that can be asked.

Comment: @lolandwow sorry, but there is no such site in Stack Exchange. You will have better luck in other places.

Comment: @ShadowWizard So, now, i should tag program? Below guys, including you, so nice :D love u.

Comment: First make clear what kind of question you have. Can you put in a sample?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Heeeee, yes :) such as , find solutions of c# bug,  how to creat a c# problem. Thank so much XD

Comment: You're going to get your butt handed to you if this is representative of the quality of your questions.  Why don't you go lurk some and see how it's done.

Comment: @Won't i come from China, my English is not very well... Read and write  English is not easy to me... So... ^^"" sorry, but thank you

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce thank you  for answering :D , but in this time point , they are sleeping now^^~~...

Comment: You're doing much better than I would be, if we were speaking in mandarin, however this is more about the format and content than the translation. We help people with the language barrier all the time.  A question written in clear, simple language that has been machine-translated is often acceptable.

Comment: @Won't Is below guys said, Tag: 1. Program ming 2.practial 3. No need to always select 5 tags? Any added point i missing? Am i summary wrong? Thx :D

Comment: That's a very generalized statement of what is appropriate. I would suggest you compose a question outside of StackOverflow and then compare it to other questions currently being asked. Is it similar to questions being downvoted? In what ways? Do upvoted questions have these similarities? You can always post an example question here and ask for editing help if you are truly stuck.

Comment: 这种说法是真实的。这也是不完整的。试着写一个问题，但不是将其提交。将它比作其他人问的问题。它是类似于 downvoted 的问题吗？在哪些方面？使你的问题更像好的问题，不像不好的问题。你可以要求编辑在这里帮助，如果你是无法做到这一点。

Comment: (I used a machine translator to do the above--I think it turned out well)

Comment: @Won't haaaaaaa. Thank you so much,  i feel you actually pay heart for me ^^. This machine translator is not well(if u want to have a chinese girlfriend, don't use it, she will leave u immediately, trust me, my brother XD) if i have any question, i will @ u. Brother always better than translator , alright XD

Answer (score 7):

If you face a **practical programming problem** you can ask about it on Stack Overflow. "Practical" is important here. It should concern code you are writing. You should clearly explain what your problem is and illustrate it with the code you have written so far.

If it's a bug, show us the minimal amount of code that allows us to reproduce the bug. Explain what you want the code to do, and how the result you get differs from what you want.

If your questions are however more broad (How do I finish this program? How do I pick up a new language? What are the best libraries to do X? What would you recommend for ...?) then your question is likely to be off-topic over there and to the best of my knowledge on most programming-related sites within the network.

As for tags, at a minimum add the tag of the language you're using. If you don't know what other tags to add, just let it be. Those who know will add them for you. There is no need to always select 5 tags, and you don't want to add just any tag.